# Is it possible to inspect a MS SQL Server dump (.dat-binary, exported with bcp)?

Tags: sql-server, bcp, windows-server

I have issues importing a binary .dat-file that has been generated with the cmd-line tool bcp. Besides the unhelpful error messages I get (invalid field size for datatype ; but no mention of which column and or datatype) I have nothing to go with. I did not generate the bcp file, so there is that.

It's a large file and I have not encountered any means to see the contents!

- Is it somehow possible to convert the the binrary .dat file into a flat text .csv file?
- Is it possible to just extract the first couple of rows into clear text?

Thank you for any hints.